# nav-stacked's list element cannot be hide bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to hide following nav-stacked list `ios` class contained `<li>` element. I used this code for it. But it doesn't work at all. but background-color is apply for that element. Why is that. I use Bootstrap 3

```
 .ios {
    dispaly : none;
 }
```

here is my html code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar nav-pills nav-stacked">

    <li id="ios-parent">
        <a href="#" class="hvr-fade"><b class="fa fa-forumbee"></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;iOS</a>
    </li>

    <li class="sub-menu">
        <a href="#" class="hvr-fade"><b class="fa fa-forumbee"></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;iOS1</a>
    </li>

    <li class="sub-menu ios">
        <a href="#" class="hvr-fade"><b class="fa fa-forumbee"></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;iOS2</a>
    </li>

    <li class="sub-menu">
        <a href="#" class="hvr-fade"><b class="fa fa-forumbee"></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;iOS3</a>
    </li>

    <li class="sub-menu">
        <a href="#" class="hvr-fade"><b class="fa fa-forumbee"></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;iOS4</a>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

you have a typo:

```
.ios {
    display : none;
}
```

instead of `dispaly`

EDIT

Assuming that the spelling in your CSS is correct, it is probably a matter of your selector being overriden.

In Bootstrap:

```
.nav > li {
    display: block;
}
```

this is more specific than your `.ios` selector, try replacing your one with:

```
.nav > .ios {
    display: none;
}
```

which will make it specific enough to override Bootstrap styling. You can easily see what is being applied using the web inspector in your browser

Comment: I'm typed like that. Isn't it?